# Remove unnecessary padding from table rows in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to code the below design in html and css

[image]

The result I got:

[image]

I want to center other content in the td elements, so it will be aligned with the product image. I tried to use display: list-item with the product image and it works in Chrome, like the below image:

[image]

CSS code:

```
table {
        width: 100%;

        thead {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }

        th {
            text-align: left;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #909090;
            padding-bottom: 1em;
        }

        .thumb {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #f7f7f7;
            border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
            display: list-item;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: #fafafa;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
            border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        }

        td,
        tr {
            padding: 1em 0;
            span {
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/ahpegfvj/)

Thanks,

Comment: The fiddle you provided seems fine to me (FF, Ch)

Comment: In that third image you have shown, that does not look “centered” (on the vertical axis), but aligned to the top instead. If that is what you want – then simply specify `vertical-align` for the table cells accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that third image you have shown, that does not look “centered” (on the vertical axis), but aligned to the top instead. If that is what you want – then simply specify `vertical-align` for the table cells accordingly:

```
.cart table td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahpegfvj/3/